# calling function from view in codeigniter not working

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I am calling controller function from view with base url it's going to that function but showing 404 Page Not Found. 
.htaccess I am using is this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On 
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA] 
</IfModule>
```

config.php

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

autoload is

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('form', 'url', 'security');
```

default controller in routes.php is

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'prog_bar';
```

base_url is

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost:8080/jsLearning/prog_bar/';
```

view

```
a href="<?php echo base_url().'file_func'; ?>">abc</a>
```

controller

```
        <?php
    defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

    class prog_bar extends CI_Controller {

            public function index()
            {
                    $this->load->view('prog_bar_view');

            }


            public function file_func(){

                echo "form";
            }        
    }
```

what else I am missing?

Comment: So what happens if you use http://localhost:8080/index.php/jsLearning/ or http://localhost:8080/index.php/jslearning/ ? Are you using windows or linux?

Answer (score 1):

Class name should be started with capital letter,
Change this

```
class prog_bar extends CI_Controller {
```

to

```
class Prog_bar extends CI_Controller {
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `base_url` is wrong. It should be

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost:8080/jsLearning/';
```

and now in HTML use `site_url()` instead `base_url()` like

```
<a href="<?php echo site_url('prog_bar/file_func'); ?>">abc</a>
```

`base_url()` should be used only for resources link like image file, css file etc

Update your `.htaccess` by following

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: can you show the URL you trying to access. `http://localhost:8080/jsLearning/prog_bar/file_func` ??

Comment: answer updated. change your `.htaccess` as in answer

Comment: NOP NOT WORKING

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be great with settings below:

In Config.php:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost:8080/jsLearning/';
```

In Your View:

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>file_func">abc</a>
```

In Your Controller:

```
 class Prog_bar extends CI_Controller {
```

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

If you have still error, check to see what your base_url link to..Create a link

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>">Base Url</a>
```

to see in your browser where it links.

Answer (score 0):

You do not use the base url for links within the site. Use the controller name and the methods name

```
<?php echo anchor("Pages/entry", "Post Entry"); ?>
```

What is form? It is not defined. Is it a page? if so, you have no view address for it. If its a snippet, you still need an address

```
$this->load->view('prog_bar_view')
```

a function will not simply show a view or snippet without being told where it is. If you are trying to include a form in a page, then just use nested views and in your main(html) view load the view you are trying to show with $this->load->view()